# For some reason when I query the db and name the variable user_db then flash the variable user_db.hashed_password I get None. Why is this?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Sorry I didn't include the html files and every import.

I tried to create the simplest example possible. Hopefully the code runs.
I shortened the login function on purpose.

When I query the db and name the variable `user_db`, then I try to flash the variables `flash(user_db.username)` and `flash(user_db.username)` I get the output of the username and email. If I go `flash(user_db.hashed_password)` the output is `None`.

Why is  `user_db.hashed_password` output `None`?

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    hashed_password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    
 
    from argon2 import PasswordHasher

    def hash_password(self, plaintext_password_form):
        ph = PasswordHasher()
        self.password_hashed_form  = ph.hash(plaintext_password_form)
        return self.password_hashed_form 
    


    
    def compare_hashed_passwords(self, hashed_password_db, plaintext_password_form):
        '''   
        The code runs in the /login route.
        You should query the db for hashed_password 
        or the value will be a different hash; 
        and the function ph.verify will return False even 
        if the password form match with the hash password.
        '''
        
        ph = PasswordHasher()
        try:
            ph.verify(hashed_password_db, plaintext_password_form)
            signedin = True
        except:
            signedin = False
        return signedin
        # have to redirect 
    


@app.route("/home", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
   render_template(home.html)







class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    '''
    This is in /register route.
    The forms are username, email, password and confirm_password
    '''
    username = StringField('username')
    
    email = StringField('email')


    password = PasswordField('password')
 
    confirm_password = PasswordField('confirm_password')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit'),




   

@app.route("/register", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def register():

    # if the user is logged in make so they can't go to the register page. 
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for(('auth.home')))
    
    form = RegistrationForm()
    # form.validate_on_submit(): are always the same line of render template to always allow a get request.
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        username_form = form.username.data
        email_form = form.email.data
        plaintext_password_form = form.password.data
        confirm_plaintext_password_form = form.confirm_password.data
        # Use the code, if you are adding code to the database the first time
        adding_user = User(username=username_form, email=email_form)
        # hash the password    
        hashed_password_form = adding_user.hash_password(plaintext_password_form)
        
     
        
        
        adding_user_hahed_password = User(hashed_password=hashed_password_form)
        db.session.add(adding_user, adding_user_hahed_password )
        db.session.commit()
               
       
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return render_template('register.html',title='register', form=form)






def check_if_username_or_email_is_in_db(form, field):
    '''
    if the username or email is in the db the code works,
    if not it raises an ValidationError.
    The if statement checks if the query is empty/has no values in db.
    This runs in the LoginForm in auth/forms.py
    '''
  
 
    # if empty list [] return True 
    if not User.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first() or not User.query.filter_by(username=field.data).first(): 
        raise ValidationError('The username or email does not exist. Please retype your username or email.')   



# I included this validator because I am not sure if that could be causing the error. 
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    '''
    This is in /Login route.
    The forms are username, email, password and confirm_password
    '''
    
    username_or_email = StringField('username_or_email', validators=
    [
    check_if_username_or_email_is_in_db
    ])    
    
    password = PasswordField('password')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
  



@app.route("/login",methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    # if the user is logged in make it so they can't go to the login page. 
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('auth.home')) 

    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # allows you to register with a username or email
        username_or_email_form = form.username_or_email.data
        plaintext_password_form = form.password.data
 

        username_db = User.query.filter_by(username=username_or_email_form).first()
        email_db = User.query.filter_by(email=username_or_email_form).first()
                
        if username_db.username == username_or_email_form:
            user_db = User.query.filter_by(username=username_or_email_form ).first()
            flash(user_db)

        elif email_db.email == username_or_email_form:
            user_db = User.query.filter_by(email=username_or_email_form).first()
        else:
            flash('username or email do not exist')
            flash(user_db)
        
               
        flash(user_db.hashed_password)
        
        hashed_password_db = user_db.hashed_password
        return render_template('home.html')

           

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by have 2 instances of the `User()...`. Just for clarity the 2 instances were `adding_user = User(username=username_form, email=email_form)` and `adding_user_hahed_password = User(hashed_password=hashed_password_form)`.

Then in the login route when I try to access 1 `user_db = User.query.filter_by(...).first()`. I am only using 1 instance of `User`.

Put simply `user_db.hashed_password` will return None because there are 2 `User(username=username_form, email_form)` and `User=(hashed_password=hashed_password_form)` each containing separate attributes. With `user_db.hashed_password` I am using the username or email while querying and this was causing the error.